# adding a picture to the middle of a drawn rectangle [iPhone]

Tags: iphone

I have the following code that I am using to draw a simple rectangle inside the middle of a drawn circle, however I would like to be able to replace this rectangle with an UIImage, does anyone know how this can be done?

```
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 255.0/255.0, 255.0/255.0, 255.0/255.0, 1.0);
CGMutablePathRef path = [self newPathForRect:CGRectMake(center.x - kRoundedRectRadius, center.y - kRoundedRectRadius, kRoundedRectRadius * 2.0, kRoundedRectRadius * 2.0)];
CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
CGPathRelease(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll no longer be able to use a `CGPathRef` to do it, but the [CGContextDrawImage()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-F17017) function will do what you want. Just pass in the result of `-[UIImage CGImage]`:

```
rect = CGRectMake(
    center.x - kRoundedRectRadius,
    center.y - kRoundedRectRadius,
    kRoundedRectRadius * 2.0,
    kRoundedRectRadius * 2.0
);

CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, myImage.CGImage);
```

Comment: can you please provide a bit of code to help me since im confused about how to add the contextDrawImage to the path i want to add it to